# Align approximately colocated vector points for comparison

Tags: qgis, elevation, topography, land-survey

I have a more general, methodological question and do not have much knowledge about GIS techniques.

I have 6 topographic survey ([x,y,z] point clouds), each representing the same dune/beach system at different points in time. The surveys were conducted so as to have each point be as close as possible to the same point in the previous survey. Of course, the positions are not actually identical, but do represent the evolution of the beach at a given point through time due to storms, etc.

I would like to compare the change in elevation through time on a point-by-point basis. Should I just define a buffer around each point in a survey and clip the successive survey, in an attempt to capture the correct point in the buffer for comparison?

The data sets have 10000+ points and I can envision this become sloppy with overlapping buffers, etc. If you know of a more precise method or strategy to tackle this problem, let me know and I can read the documentation. Also, if I need to rephrase the question, let me know, my GIS lingo is also poor.

Comment: You could use a proximity operator, like Near but this will indeed fail as the dunes drift father and a different dune becomes closer. Can you isolate individual dunes as linestrings? If so it becomes easier to identify general trends. If not, do the dunes generally move in a particular cardinal? You could create a wedge shaped geometry as a search... but that would be *a lot* of code.

Comment: To achieve comparison of elevations over time you definitely want to interpolate the points to elevation **rasters**, then compare the rasters over time.  Using, i.e. GRASS you could import the point clouds (see https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/LIDAR  for details) then use the capabilities of temporal datasets (https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/temporalintro.html) to do comparisons. In the GRASS wiki there's a nice demo of changes in dunes over time.

Comment: @MichaelMiles-Stimson. There is basically one dune, if any, maybe just a berm. The beach elevations around here are very, very low. The surveys run normal to the shoreline (cross-shore). Some of the survey transects come as individual files which makes for easy identification of particular survey lines. Others come as *.csv with x,y,z columns for all the points. It is probably possible to isolate each cross-shore survey, if it can help. Also, the dune crest is a pretty straight line and runs SW to NE.

Comment: @Micha I considered 2D interpolation and finding the difference in elevations between surfaces. However, I think the interpolation error will be on the same order as the change in elevation. In the alongshore direction, the interpolation step would be > 250' and the change in elevation is probably a few feet at most between surveys. I'll do the math on this though. Thanks for GRASS references, I've been meaning to glance through their documentation.

Comment: I'd assume that the "alongshore" elevations hardly change at all, so maybe 250' is OK? If transects are closely spaced then interpolation might work. As for the GRASS references, it will take more than a glance ;-)

Comment: @Micha I am getting bad results using the TINing method from the interpolation plugin to qgis. The space in between  surveys in disproportionally influenced by the large negative values offshore. See the data [here](https://filestogeaux.lsu.edu/public/download.php?FILE=cjoh296/84458Y6E6z9) and the resulting TIN interpolation (dx=2m) [here](https://filestogeaux.lsu.edu/public/download.php?FILE=cjoh296/4398nucNFA). Pretty sure this is a common problem but cursory googling hasn't revealed any references. A highly resolved IDW interpolation didn't help much. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the image you posted, it seems there are plenty of points to do create elevation rasters by interpolating. The GRASS module v.surf.rst ("regularized spline with tension") usually does a good job with elevations. Can you share the actual data?

Comment: @Micha Sure. Can I send you a link to the data privately? Does a shapefile work?

Comment: @Micha Also, I began experimenting with the v.surf.idw command through QGIS. It produces the expected results, but the computation time get really slow for resolutions < 10m. I think I need to mask the interpolation, but this functionality doesn't seem to be available through QGIS. I'm trying to get the GRASS shell integration working in QGIS. Seems like I have a few tools at my disposal, but don't know their pros/cons or really much about their use-cases. Is a GRASS shell within QGIS a good approach? Does GRASS have python bindings?

Comment: Yes, send a link to the data privately. Yes, the GRASS shell should be available a part of the **GRASS Toolbox** (plugin) - but not thru the QGIS Processing framework. And yes, all GRASS can be run thru the python bindings. See the  [GRASS Wiki](https://grasswiki.osgeo.org/wiki/GRASS_and_Python)

Comment: @Micha I figured it out, [screen capture](https://filestogeaux.lsu.edu/public/download.php?FILE=cjoh296/71207IDsIV0), thanks to your [comment](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244097/v-surf-idw-ignores-mask) a while back.  However, the interpolation is pretty slow for finer resolutions. I'll start looking into parallelized versions of GRASS to solve this. Thanks again

Comment: Nice job! How slow is it? and how fine is the resolution?

Comment: @Micha It was taking probably ~2hrs for 10m resolution using v.surf.idw. I reread the [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244097/v-surf-idw-ignores-mask) I referenced before and realized idw was **not** applying a mask to the interpolation computations, but the rst method **does indeed** mask the computation. Using the rst method, with the appropriate mask, I was computing the whole thing at 2m resolution in 5-8 mins average. This was also in the GRASS shell, not QGIS.